# Pygt4 live updating graph

Tags: graph, pyqt4, python-3.4, auto-update

for my project I need to make a graph that shows 15 points and updates the density over time. In my code I got a function that returns a float that represents the density. I want to show the density over time. I searched a lot on stackoverflow / google to find a proper example but I couldn't find one. I need my graph in a subplot. Currently I'm using a FigureCanvas to make my plot. 
Can someone give me an example how to make a live updating graph? I think I should use something like numpy.append, and make the first point disappear.

the code that I currently use:

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.hold(False)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
         pass

 class MyDynamicMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """A canvas that updates itself every second with a new plot."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyMplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
            timer.timeout.connect(self.update_figure)
            timer.start(1000)

def update_figure(self):
    #code to update the figure
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a timer connected to a function.

Supply your updated data in `update_figure` and redraw the figure - just, as it is done in the example, you'd copied the code from